# Alternatives to numpy looping and where condition

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have 2 numpy arrays which are extremely big. How to get the index of array 2 in array1 based on a condition? The condition is: for each value in array1 find the first value in array 2 and copy the index - 2 to array 1. I hope this makes sense. I have an illustration below of what i mean.

Numpy Array 1

```
+---------+------------+
| IndexNr |   Value    |
+---------+------------+
|       0 | 1485963480 |
|       1 | 1486029060 |
|       2 | 1486032900 |
|       3 | 1486032960 |
|       4 | 1486033020 |
|       5 | 1486033080 |
|       6 | 1486034940 |
|       7 | 1486038480 |
|       8 | 1486039140 |
|       9 | 1486039320 |
|      10 | 1486039500 |
|      11 | 1486041300 |
|      12 | 1486044360 |
|      13 | 1486048740 |
|      14 | 1486049880 |
|      15 | 1486049940 |
|      16 | 1486050240 |
|      17 | 1486114200 |
|      18 | 1486119840 |
|      19 | 1486119900 |
|      20 | 1486120380 |
|      21 | 1486134720 |
|      22 | 1486134780 |
|      23 | 1486135380 |
|      24 | 1486135440 |
+---------+------------+
```

Numpy Array 2

```
+---------+------------+
| IndexNr |   Value    |
+---------+------------+
|       0 | 1485963300 |
|       1 | 1486029000 |
|       2 | 1486032600 |
|       3 | 1486032900 |
|       4 | 1486034700 |
|       5 | 1486038300 |
|       6 | 1486038900 |
|       7 | 1486039200 |
|       8 | 1486041300 |
|       9 | 1486044300 |
|      10 | 1486048500 |
|      11 | 1486049700 |
|      12 | 1486114200 |
|      13 | 1486119900 |
|      14 | 1486120200 |
|      15 | 1486134600 |
+---------+------------+
```

to something like this

```
+-------+-------------+
| Index | ArrayIndex2 |
+-------+-------------+
|     0 | nan         |
|     1 | nan         |
|     2 | nan         |
|     3 | 2           |
|     4 | 2           |
|     5 | 2           |
|     6 | 3           |
|     7 | 4           |
|     8 | 5           |
|     9 | 6           |
|    10 | 6           |
|    11 | 6           |
|    12 | 8           |
|    13 | 9           |
|    14 | 10          |
|    15 | 10          |
|    16 | 10          |
|    17 | 10          |
|    18 | 11          |
|    19 | 11          |
|    20 | 13          |
|    21 | 14          |
|    22 | 14          |
|    23 | 14          |
|    24 | 14          |
+-------+-------------+
```

Here is my solution on how i do it.

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([1486029060,1486032720,1486032900,1486032960,1486033020,1486033080,1486034940,1486038480,1486039140,1486039320,1486039500,1486041300,1486044360,1486048740,1486049880,1486049940,1486050240,1486114200,1486119840,1486119900,1486120380,1486134720,1486134780,1486135380,1486135440])
array2 = np.array([1485963300,1486029000,1486032600,1486032900,1486034700,1486038300,1486038900,1486039200,1486041300,1486044300,1486048500,1486049700,1486114200,1486119900,1486120200,1486134600])

# create an empty holder with the same size as array 1
array1_result = np.empty((array1.shape[0], 1))
array1_result.fill(np.nan)

# loop and create result array
for rowNr in range(array1.shape[0]):
    if (rowNr > 2):
        currentRowValue = array1[rowNr]
        array1_result[rowNr] = np.reshape(np.array(np.where(array2 < currentRowValue)), (-1, 1))[-2][0] #array2Index

print(array1_result)
```

The only problem is that this looping is very inefficient on big arrays. Both array1 and array2 are a few million rows and it is extremely slow using this this method. Is there any other way of achieving the same result?

Comment: To be clear, you want `array1_result[i]` = min `j` where `array1[i] < array2[j]`?

Comment: i just need the (indexNr - 2) of array 2 where the value from array 1 is smaller than the first match on array 2. Does it make any sense? :)

Comment: if it is of any help, the values in both arrays are actually UNIX time

Comment: Is array2 guaranteed to be sorted? Are both?

Comment: yes, they are guaranteed sorted

Comment: will both arrays have same length or varying lengths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)

```
>>> np.searchsorted(array2, array1)
array([ 2,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  8,  8, 10, 11, 12, 12, 12,
       12, 13, 13, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16], dtype=int64)
```

Or encoding your "but not the first two rows" condition

```
>>> np.searchsorted(array2, array1[2:]) - 2
array([ 1,  2,  2,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  6,  6,  8,  9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11,
       11, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14], dtype=int64)
>>> np.concatenate(([0,0], _))
array([ 0,  0,  1,  2,  2,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  6,  6,  8,  9, 10, 10, 10,
   10, 11, 11, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14], dtype=int64)
```

This disagrees in one place - that `1`. I think this is the difference between equality and inequality

Comment: Thank you @Eric this is both really fast and accurate

Answer (score 0):

Without the initial `nan` values, this matches your `array1_result`:

```
In [263]: A = array2<array1[3:,None]
In [264]: idx2 = np.sum(A,axis=1)-2
In [265]: idx2
Out[265]: 
array([ 2,  2,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  6,  6,  8,  9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14])
```

`A` is a (22,16) array, with True were `array2` is smaller.  I count the number of `True` per row.  The rest is adjusting for the 2 offset.

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj for the answer :)